# Why projection window is between -1 and 1

Tags: opengl, projection, projection-matrix

Is it a convetion ? What we achieve with this ?

I am reading about how the perspective and orthographic matrix is getting calculated and everyone is trying to normalize the homogenous coordinates to [-1,1]

Thank you !

[Orthographic Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_projection)

Comment: I can't write a full answer to this, but I think it has something to do with making it faster to clip the vertices/triangles that are not visible. [This answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/158859/40264) is the best I've found about this.

Comment: This is called **Normalized Device Coordinates** and is discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693231/normalized-device-coordinates